# How to include custom locations for indexing in start menu search?

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, search, start-menu

I like to use new start menu search in windows vista/7. It is easy to launch application and documents by typing few characters.

Is it possible to include more locations in start menu search. For example, many of my small utilities are located in D:\Utils. I would like them to appear in Start menu search.

Note: I wouldn't like to move my utils folder in start menu folder just to make search working.

Comment: Great question btw! +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Vistaclues.com has the solution for you!](http://www.vistaclues.com/search-a-custom-folder/)

> Windows Vista automatically index the
>   places that matter most: all user
>   profiles (including Documents,
>   Pictures, Videos, Music, etc), your
>   Start menu (so you can find
>   applications by name), your e-mail
>   (for Outlook, anyway), your notes (for
>   OneNote), and any Offline Files you’ve
>   configured.
>
> So, if you play by the rules and store
>   everything in Documents, Pictures, or
>   the other standard folders, you’re all
>   set. If you’re a stubborn old coot who
>   insists on storing your files at
>   C:\MyFiles\ or something like that,
>   well, it’s not being index. BTW, I’m a
>   stubborn old coot.
>
> To add a custom folder to the index,
>   follow these steps:
>
> - Click Start, and then click Control Panel.
> - Click System And Maintenance.
> - Click Indexing Options.
> - Click Modify.
> - The Indexed Locations dialog appears. Click Show all locations, and
>     then provide administrative
>     credentials at the UAC prompt.
>
> [image]
>
> - In the Change selected locations list, select the check box for the
>     folder you want to add to the index.
>     Don’t overdo it and select your whole
>     C:\ drive–indexing will take too long,
>     and you’ll get a lot of garbage
>     results. Try to be as precise as
>     possible. Click OK.
>
> [image]
>
> - Click Close.
>
> If you’re indexing unusual file types
>   (like log files), be sure to index
>   that file type.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. There is one more think you need to do to make sure it appears in start menu. Right Click Start menu > Start Menu > Customize > Search files > Select "Search Entire Index". I don't have enough reputation to edit your answer. Please update your answer to make it complete.