# How to include custom *network* locations for indexing in Start Menu search?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-vista, search, start-menu

[Hemant](https://superuser.com/users/585/hemant) asked [How to include custom locations for indexing in Start Menu search?](https://superuser.com/q/61312/150988), which asks how he can get Windows Vista/7 to include his custom `D:\Utils` folder in Start Menu search.
I have a similar question, but I want to index a network location; specifically a folder in a network location on a Seagate Goflex home NAS drive. How can I do this?

Comment: I'm assuming you're referring to a unc path and not a mapped drive?

Comment: I suspect it is a unc path, it will on occasion appear under "Computer" in the removable storage section under your mounted drives (C:), but most reliably found in the "computer" field in "network" I hope that answers your question as I am not certain of the difference between unc and mapped locations.